# What mechanism/value is used to determine value of line protocol?

Tags: layer2

All books that I read will say value of line protocol (up/down) is indicator whether data link layer is working or not. Let us look at diagram below by [IEEE regarding Ethernet, page 2](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee802/download/802.3-2008_section2.pdf).

[image]

If line protocol (up/down) is indicator whether data link layer is working or not, they why when devices that process data link layer PDU, e.g. switch, router, connected to devices that do not process data link layer PDU (repeater), e.g. hub, media converter, have value of line protocol up?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/338112/cisco-switch-link-status-up-protocol-down

Comment: @Ron It does not have answer to my question.

Comment: What You mean by "line protocol"? I don't found it in http://standards.ieee.org/getieee802/download/802.3-2008_section2.pdf . If You mean "Link status (MII)", AFAIK it work on PHY layer and only on recieve.

Comment: @mmv-ru It is based on experience with ethernet interface on few brands of switch/router. If you execute command #show interface <interface>, there is line like 'Interface FastEthernet0/0 is up, line protocol is up'. It is also same for serial interface.